# Macro expansion for macros with arguments vs. variables with the same name

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

Consider the following **C** program (ignore the double side-effect issue):

```
#define max(a, b) (a>b?a:b)

int main(void){
    int max = max(5,6);
    return max;
}
```

The GCC preprocessor turns this into:

```
int main(void){
    int max = (5>6?5:6);
    return max;
}
```

Which is quite nice, since you don't have to worry about unintentional collisions between `max` and `max()`. The [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function_002dlike-Macros.html#Function_002dlike-Macros) says:

> A function-like macro is only expanded if its name appears with a pair of parentheses after it. If you write just the name, it is left alone

Is this standardized or just something done by convention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the behavior here is well-defined.

Your macro `max` is a function-like macro (i.e., when you define it, its name is followed immediately by a left parenthesis and it takes arguments).

A use of `max` later in your code is only an invocation of that macro if the use of `max` is followed by a left parenthesis.  So, these would not invoke the `max` macro:

```
int max;
max = 42;
```

But these would all invoke the max macro:

```
max(1, 2)
max (1, 2)
max
(
    1, 2
)
max()
```

(Note that the last line is ill-formed because the number of arguments does not match the number of parameters.  This is still a macro invocation, though, and would cause a compilation error.)

This behavior is mandated by the C langauge standard.  C99 §6.10.3/10 states that after a function-like macro has been defined,

> Each subsequent instance of the function-like macro name followed by a `(` as the next preprocessing token introduces the sequence of preprocessing tokens that is replaced by the replacement list in the definition (an invocation of the macro).

Comment: I'm confused. It looks like gcc honored the max macro, and did not instead call the real max function.

Comment: @octopusgrabbus:  What `max` function?

Comment: Found the relevant part in the GCC manual, but I still don't know if this is standardized or just an informal convention

Comment: This is part of the C and C++ preprocessor specification.  That's what was meant by "the behavior here is well-defined."  I've added the relevant text from the specification.  (I don't have a copy of C11 handy, but the specification is assuredly unchanged.)